# Simple_form_for custom label

Tags: ruby-on-rails, simple-form

```
<%= f.input :body, 'Send Update:' %>
```

This returns a Symbol to Integer error.

I need the box to be titled 'Send Update:' and not 'Body'

Comment: What you mean by titled? Its name should be send_update?

Comment: In my :updates table, the column is called body. But when users go to the form, i want that text box labeled "Send Update" or something different.

Comment: Something like this?: Send Update: [heres your f.input] ?

Comment: 'Body:' still shows up.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From [documentation](https://github.com/plataformatec/simple_form/blob/master/README.md):

```
<%= simple_form_for @user do |f| %>
  <%= f.input :username, label: 'Your username please' %>
  <%= f.input :remember_me, inline_label: 'Yes, remember me' %>
  <%= f.input :email, label_html: { class: 'my_class' } %>
  <%= f.input :password_confirmation, label: false %>

  <%= f.button :submit %>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps what you are looking for its for a label/text to precede your input? You could write it on plain text, assuming your view is an ***html.erb*** file: (using table for display convenience)

```
<table>
 <tr>
  <td>Send Update: </td>
  <td><%= f.input :body %></td>
 </tr>
</table>
```

Or use the `f.label`:

```
<table>
 <tr>
  <td><%= f.label :body, "Send Update:" %></td>
  <td><%= f.input :body %></td>
 </tr>
</table>
```

UPDATE: Doing some research, found out that this could work too:

```
<%= f.input :body, label: "Send Update:" %>
```

Comment: No. this just creates a table. I am using simple_form_for. not Form_for.

Comment: I stated that the use of "table" was for displaying convenience. Its completely optional.

Comment: Update did it. Im guessing i forgot a comma or something before. Thanks a lot Oscar!